# How to add 2D arrays to a list in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, xna

I want to make a list of 2D (boolean) arrays. I have declared the empty list *block* itself and made an empty 2D boolean array called *blockStructure*. Also I made a method *blocks* where I give *blockStructure* a different value and then add it to the to the *block* list.

```
class TetrisBlock 
{
    public List<bool[,]> block;
    public bool[,] blockStructure;
}

public Tetrisblock(Texture2D sprite)
{
    blockTexture = sprite;
    blockStructure = new bool[2, 2];
}

List<bool[,]> blocks()
{
    blockStructure = new bool[,] // first 2D array 
    {
        { false, true},
        { false, false}
    };
    block.Add(blockStructure);

    blockStructure = new bool[,] // second 2D array
    {
        { true, true},
        { false, false}
    };
    block.Add(blockStructure);

    return block;
}

public void draw (GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        {
            if (blok[1][x,y])
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, new Vector2(blockTexture.Width*x, blockTexture.Height*y, Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I get says that list *block* has value null. For some reason the 2D arrays don't get added to the list. Does someone know a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You must initialize** the `List<bool[,]> block` list before you can add items to it. This line just defines the reference which at first refers to nothing, `null`, but you must have a `block = new List<bool[,]>()` for the list to be initialized

Answer (score 1):

You never gave `block` a value:

```
block = new List<bool[,]>();
```

Any reference type is `null` by default until you instantiate it to something.